# Adding Label Classes to Polyline in MapInfo Pro

Tags: labeling, mapinfo

I want to add 2 label classes to one polyline shapefile using x,y coords.

I need to add the arrival time along the line from the start (x_start & y_start) 
& the finishing time along the line from the end (X_end & y_end)

Can this be achieved through an expression?

I have created the desired output in QGIS and ArcGIS (see image below), but I need to replicate this in MapInfo if possible.

[image: Start&End Time]

Comment: are you looking to show one label at the beginning of the polyline and another label at the end? Could you maybe share an iimage of what you are looking to do? Thanks

Comment: I have added a picture for you. Yes, I am looking to add one label at the beginning with a 'start_time' field & one label at the end with a 'end_time' field.